# What's the difference between net.layers.blobs and net.params in Caffe

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe, pycaffe

I am using Python Caffe, and confused with net.layers[layer_index].blobs and net.params[layer_type]. If I understand well, net.params contains all the network parameters. Take the LeNet for example, net.params['conv1'] represents the network coefficients for the 'conv1' layer. Then net.layer[layer_index].blobs should represent the same. However, what I found is that they are not exactly the same. I use the following codes to test it:

```
def _differ_square_sum(self,blobs):
    import numpy as np
    gradients = np.sum(np.multiply(blobs[0].diff,blobs[0].diff)) + np.sum(np.multiply(blobs[1].diff,blobs[1].diff))
    return gradients


def _calculate_objective(self, iteration, solver):
    net = solver.net
    params = net.params
    params_value_list = list(params.keys())
    [print(k,v.data.shape) for k,v in net.blobs.items()]

    layer_num = len(net.layers)
    j = 0
    for layer_index in range(layer_num):
        if(len(net.layers[layer_index].blobs)>0):
            cur_gradient = self._differ_square_sum(net.layers[layer_index].blobs)
            key = params_value_list[j]
            cur_gradient2 = self._differ_square_sum(params[key])
            print([cur_gradient,cur_gradient2])
            assert(cur_gradient == cur_gradient2)
```

Any ideas on the difference between them? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are mixing the *trainable* net parameters (stored in `net.params`) and the input *data* to the net (stored in `net.blobs`):
Once you are done training the model, `net.params` are fixed and will not change. However, for each new input example you are feeding to the net, `net.blobs` will store the different layers' response to that particular input.